# \\\\$ converted to \$ in jsp template data

Tags: jsp, escaping, quoting

I just stumbled unto a weirdness in my JSP code. It seems that a double backslash followed by a dollar or percent symbol gets converted to a single backslash (plus symbol).

That is, the following JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
\\#
\\$
\\%
\\^
```

gets rendered as:

```
\\#
\$
\%
\\^
```

I'm using JDK 1.6.0_02 and Apache Tomcat 5.5.23 and 6.0.16 (two machines).

Is this a bug in Tomcat? JDK? Or is it conforming to some obscure option in the JSP spec? I tried looking at the spec but couldn't find anything useful.

Workarounds are fairly trivial, I just thought I'd file a bug in case it is one.

**EDIT**: Heh, stackoverflow also mangles backslashes

Comment: But not in the title element. It's different between the title and the heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$ is in the [spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr152/index.html) (Section JSP.1.6). "Only when EL is enabled for the page...., a literal $ can be quoted by \$.

\% will probably be because "A literal <% is quoted by <\%". I suspect that the parser isn't checking for the < before the \%.